# HBase Region Start and Stop Keys

Tags: hbase

How HBase decides what should be the `start` and `stop` key for a region.
I am actually interested to understand how does `scan` works in HBase.
If the data is stored across the nodes. How does `HBASE` perform sorting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't specify anything, when you create a table. HBase will create a single region that will contains all the keys. As soon the region gets too large, the region will be split in two, and so on.
Each region has the data in it sorted, so the scan will start from the region that contains the first-key and keep going.

take a look at this blog post, that should explain with a bit more details what is going on.
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/how-scaling-really-works-in-apache-hbase/